# How to solve Incorrect date value?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, orm

I have a form. Form has a 2 date picker. Which are names Date1 and Date2. Date1 is must be filled but Date2 is optional. If i filled a form I can save record but when I save form without date2 value I got an error.

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '' for column 'end_date' at row
values (344, q, q, q, Q, Q, q, q, 0(, qq, 2222-02-22, , 2022-11-15 22:51:53, 2022-11-15 22:51:53))
```

How can I save empty date? I try to if post empty $date2 = null but doesnt work.

Comment: To save null as value in the end_date field, it needs to be nullable (in your DB).

Comment: its default value is null also $date2=null but as you can see in value , , it is not correct

Comment: as N69S says make the database column for end_date nullable (allow nulls) its not a php / laravel issue its a database constraint

Comment: As i told u it is nullable + default value is null already.